# appending function results to an list in R

Tags: r, list, function, return, append

I have created some functions that produce plots. The goal is to store the functions outcome in one list `analysisObjects`. `analysisObjects` is a list of lists. The code below produces the outcome exactly as expected.

```
createPlot1 <- function(data = mtcars){
  
 plot1 <- ggplot(data, aes(factor(cyl))) +
    geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()
 
 plot2 <- ggplot(data, aes(factor(cyl))) +
    geom_boxplot() 
  
  res = list("mycars" = list(list("objType" = "plot",
                                                   "object" =  plot1),
                                              list("objType" = "plot",
                                                   "object" =  plot2)))
  
  analysisObjects <<- append(analysisObjects, res)
  
}


createPlot2 <- function(data = iris){
  
 plot1 <-  ggplot(data, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
   geom_point(aes(color=Species, shape=Species)) 
 
 plot2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +
   geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Species)) 
  
  res <- list("myflowers" = list(list("objType" = "plot",
                                            "object" =  plot1),
                                       list("objType" = "plot",
                                            "object" =  plot2)))
  
 analysisObjects <<- append(analysisObjects, res)
  
}
```

The problem is, that the analysisObject has to be created a priory and it is overwritten every time I run a function. I was trying to avoid this by writing a separate function, which appends the outcome from a function into  `analysisObjects`, if it exists. If `analysisObjects` doesnt exist, the list is created:

```
appendResults <- function(object = res){
  if(exists("analysisObjects")){
    analysisObjects <<- append(analysisObjects, object)
  }else{
    analysisObjects <<- list()
    analysisObjects <<- append(analysisObjects, object)
  }
}
```

this function replaces the line `analysisObjects <<- append(analysisObjects, res)`, but the process still seems quite ugly. Is there a better way to appending results of a function to a list? Ideally one, where the order of execution of the functions doesnt matter.

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(174)`  The operator `<<-` is dangerous.

Comment: thats what i suspected and a reason why i am looking for something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're approaching your problem with the wrong premises.

Why don't you try something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

# generic for methods dispatch
createPlot <- function(data){
 
 UseMethod("createPlot")
 
}

# method for class "someclass"
createPlot.someclass <- function(data){
 
 plot1 <- ggplot(data, aes(factor(cyl))) +
  geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()
 
 plot2 <- ggplot(data, aes(factor(cyl))) +
  geom_boxplot() 
 
 list(list("objType" = "plot", "object" =  plot1),
      list("objType" = "plot", "object" =  plot2))
 
}

# method for class "someotherclass"
createPlot.someotherclass <- function(data){
 
 plot1 <-  ggplot(data, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Species, shape=Species)) 
 
 plot2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Species)) 
 
 list(list("objType" = "plot", "object" =  plot1),
      list("objType" = "plot", "object" =  plot2))

}

# prepare your data and assign the right class. It will be needed for dispatch
class(mtcars) <- c("someclass"     , class(mtcars))
class(iris)   <- c("someotherclass", class(iris))

# make a list of your dataframes and give it a name to each one (if you want to)
mylist <- list(mycars = mtcars, myflowers = iris)

# create your list
analysisObjects <- lapply(mylist, createPlot)
```

The idea is that you create `analysisObjects` once and you create it in the best and cleanest way.

You want to have a list at the end, so I suppose you want to loop over some dataframes to get a final result.

What you can do is to prepare all your dataframes at the beginning and then at the end plot them all in a smart way.

You can exploit classes and methods, for example.

`createPlot` is a generic that dispatch thought your classes.

I just invented some names for your classes but you can make prettier names.

At the end you loop throught your data. Give out a name to each dataframe: that will be the name of each item of the list.

---

EDIT to answer your questions

If you duplicate a dataframe to assign different classes you don't get much more extra space in your memory.

Look at this example. We use the function `lobstr::obj_size` to see the actual size of RAM used by R.

```
i2 <- i1 <- iris

lobstr::obj_size(i1)
#> 7,200 B
lobstr::obj_size(i2)
#> 7,200 B
lobstr::obj_size(list(i1,i2))
#> 7,264 B

class(i1) <- c("someclass", class(i1))
class(i2) <- c("someotherclass", class(i2))

lobstr::obj_size(i1)
#> 7,272 B
lobstr::obj_size(i2)
#> 7,272 B
lobstr::obj_size(list(i1,i2))
#> 7,728 B
```

As you can see R is optimized so that even if you "create" another object it actually calls the same space in the RAM memory and it doesn't replicate everything for no reason.

If you edit a column of `i2`, then it will replicate just that one column.

So if you need to assign different classes and "replicate" your dataset is not a problem.

However, if for one specific data set you need to call two different methods you can do it this way:

```
createPlot.someotherclassyet <- function(data){

  out1 <- createPlot.someclass(data)
  out2 <- createPlot.someotherclass(data)

  c(out1, out2)

}

class(iris) <- c("someotherclassyet", class(iris))
createPlot(iris)
```

This gets the job done, but it's not really clean.

It would be better to have a function that transform a class into another one, just in case in the future you need to create checks or extra transformations to make a class as such.

```
### someclass
as_someclass <- function(x){

  UseMethod("as_someclass")

}

as_someclass.someotherclassyet <- function(x){
  
  class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "someotherclassyet")
  as_someclass(x)

}

as_someclass.data.frame <- function(x){
  
  class(x) <- c("someclass", class(x))
  x

}



### someotherclass

as_someotherclass <- function(x){

  UseMethod("as_someotherclass")

}

as_someotherclass.someotherclassyet <- function(x){
  
  class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "someotherclassyet")
  as_someotherclass(x)

}

as_someotherclass.data.frame <- function(x){
  
  class(x) <- c("someotherclass", class(x))
  x

}


### someotherclassyet
as_someotherclassyet <- function(x){

  UseMethod("as_someotherclassyet")

}

as_someotherclassyet.data.frame <- function(x){
  
  class(x) <- c("someotherclassyet", class(x))
  x

}


createPlot.someotherclassyet <- function(data){

  out1 <- createPlot(as_someclass(data))
  out2 <- createPlot(as_someotherclass(data))

  c(out1, out2)

}


lapply(list(myflowers      = as_someclass(iris),
            myotherflowers = as_someotherclass(iris),
            allmyflowers   = as_someotherclassyet(iris),
            mycars         = as_someotherclass(mtcars)),
       createPlot)
```

---

If you want to perform `createPlot` on a list of object you can create your list and assign a class.

Comment: i had to research how does the UseMethod actually work to understand what you did here. The results is as desired, the only downside of this approach is that  `class(mtcars) <- c("someclass"     , class(mtcars))
class(iris)   <- c("someotherclass", class(iris))` create two new objects. Considering i may have around 100 functions, this would clutter up my environment. Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean “it creates two new objects”? It overwrite the existing ones.

Comment: my bad, i misunderstood this. I was wondering how to deal with a case where the same dataset is used in more than one instance? say I also have a function `createPlot.someotherclassyet`, which also uses the iris dataset. Howeevr, i want the functions to be separate. That means thati would be overwriting the class before i run lapply.  How can i deal with that?

Comment: or what if a function needs both datasets? `iris` as well as `mtcars`?

Comment: look at my edit. It should answer to your questions.